# Is it possible to use passportjs for multiple accounts from the same network?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm building a service that could utilize multiple accounts from the same service.

Is there any way of assigning a user two twitter accounts? What I need are the user's access tokens.

Comment: So far I know in this case you retrieve two different users accounts. If you can combine both or not is more like to allow your application do it seeking for equals information than social API capable of.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: You mean you have a user and that user can login to your application using any of his twitter id, and both login should maintain same session. Is that you mean ?